# How does pinterest achieve its layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

In pinterest.com, the divs have variable length, yet there are no gaps between the rows.  Is it possible to get this effect using an unordered list and css?  Are they using any javascript to achieve that "compact" look? When I tried it, there is always a gap between two rows to accommodate the tallest div from the first row...

Comment: You do know you can look through the code of both the javascript and the html and css right?

Comment: Yes I did...however, they don't seem to be using unordered lists...

Comment: similar rendering method with  http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use Firebug or Chrome's web inspector, you'll see that each of the `.pin` divs has an absolute position, which is presumably set with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

It's done via [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) available on github https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Comment: Just to clarify, Pinterest does not use Masonry (at least not last time I looked at their code), but Masonry will give you a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of jQuery Plugins that archive that.

I like "Isotope - An exquisite jQuery plugin for magical layouts"

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Looks like this is similar to the Masonry plugin posted by @Francis.